# tikz block title position varies depending on text size

Tags: tikzposter

tikzposter block titles (and consequently blocks) vary quite a bit in positioning and height based on the size of the title text. I would like for blocks to be horizontally aligned without needing to ensure the text in each has similar height. For example, if I have two blocks, one with a descender and one without:

```tex
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait]{tikzposter}

\title{Poster title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{columns}
    \column{0.3}
    \block{Block A}{}
    \column{0.3}
    \block{Block g}{}
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

This results in this kind of slightly offset block, even though the only thing that's different between blocks is one letter in the block title.
[image]

I have played around a bit with changing the block style to add text depth to the title, but it doesn't seem to be applied to the title node itself and has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text depth is exactly the problem that you have here and one solution would be to manually add an invisible zero sized box through `\vphantom{}`:

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait]{tikzposter}

\title{Poster title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{columns}
    \column{0.3}
    \block{Block A\vphantom{g}}{}
    \column{0.3}
    \block{Block g}{}
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Ideally I would like to avoid having to spoof things, so that I can use this as a template for future posters.

Comment: @alanocallaghan Well you could modify the `\block` so it always adds the same depth and height, no matter what. Or better create your own `\fulldepthblock` by `\newcommand{\fulldepthblock}[2]{\block{\vphantom{Ag}#1}{\vphantom{Ag}#2}}`